# How can I specify that all R package dependencies must be built under R>=4 for a conda package?

Tags: r, conda

I wish to build a conda package for an R package from GitHub ([locuszoomr](https://github.com/myles-lewis/locuszoomr)). When running `conda build`, I've specified `R=4.3.2` as an argument, but I've repeatedly run into the following error:

`Error: package 'viridisLite' was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it`

I've resolved this by editing the `meta.yaml` produced by `conda skeleton` to specify the latest version of each dependency like `viridisLite` under the `requirements` section, under the assumption that the latest version of each would be suitable for R>4. I am able to now build my package, but it has been tedious to troubleshoot each dependency in turn. The relevant part of the `meta.yaml` now looks like this:

```
host:
    - r-base >=4.3.2
    - r-r6 >=2.5.1
    - r-memoise >=2.0.1
    - r-crayon >=1.5.2
    - r-codetools >=0.2_19
    - r-hms >=1.1.3
    - r-pkgconfig >=2.0.3
    - r-magrittr >=2.0.3
    - r-dbplyr >=2.4.0
    - bioconductor-annotationfilter
    - bioconductor-biocgenerics
    - bioconductor-genomeinfodb
    - bioconductor-ensembldb
    - r-ldlinkr
    - r-ggplot2
    - r-gtable >=0.3.4
    - r-viridislite >=0.4.2
    - r-plotly
    - r-rlang
```

Is there a faster way to do this? `conda` isn't sourcing these packages from own local R installation, presumably?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? We have streamlined procedures for adding CRAN packages to Conda Forge (see [Contributing docs](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html#contributing-packages)). Otherwise, the `-R` argument should only really be given `4.3`, without a patch specification.

Comment: @merv Thank you for your correction re: the R version number, that's helpful. I've updated the post to make explicit the package (locuszoomr, which is on CRAN) and the contents of the `meta.yaml` file. I'd like to build the latest version I've checked out from GitHub, but I'll see if it's any easier to build the CRAN version.

Comment: I see it has Bioconductor dependencies, so it would need to be build on Bioconda.